# Upgrading a .NET Core app that has project.json to the new template without project.json

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-1.1

I have an ASP.NET Core WEB API app that is using project.json and is under source control. My goal is to upgrade it completely as if I just started the project using the latest VS2017 ASP.NET Core 1.1 template.

How can I manually do this if project.json no longer exists.

Comment: Just open up the project in VS2017 and it will do the upgrade.

Comment: @nurdyguy I didn't assume Microsoft is that good, but I guess they are. Thank you very much!

Comment: or open console to the folder and type in `dotnet migrate` worked for me better during VS 2017 RC than inside VS